# Python pandas excel import NameError

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to import data from Excel into Python via Pandas on Mac. When I apply the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('/Users/andreasmelsen/Desktop/Data.xlsx', sheetname='Sheet1')
print(df)
```

I receive the following error message:

```
NameError: name 'df' is not defined
```

Am I missing something? I have no issues importing Pandas.

**Edit:** I am using Visual Studio Code v1.52.1 with Python 3.9.0 64 bit)

Comment: Please provide the full trace back. Also, are you using jupyter?

Comment: @It_is_Chris: No I am using VS code (I have edited the question.

Comment: Can you also provide the full traceback of the error to the question?'

Comment: Is this code, inside a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the error to be that I had not installed `openpyxl`, which I installed by typing `pip3 install openpyxl` in my terminal.

Thanks to all who had commented.

Comment: See my correction below regarding sheet_name

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'/Users/andreasmelsen/Desktop/Data.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
```

I have added r before the path & corrected the variable name of sheet_name

Answer (score 1):

Try: `global df`

before `df = pd.read_excel('/Users/andreasmelsen/Desktop/Data.xlsx', sheetname='Sheet1')`